# Is there a way to use one function to replace two similar functions in C++

Tags: c++

The following code compiles and runs fine. But, to me, there are repeated code in funtions `workflow1` and `workflow2`.In fact, the only differences are the added parameter `y` in `workflow2`, and the different calls to `method1`/`method2`.  Is there a way to use one function to replace those two? Maybe there is a way to pass a function (`workflow1` or `workflow2`) and its parameters as parameters to another general function (say, `workflow`)? Maybe there exist some design patterns for this kind of job?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void workflow1(int x) {
        doThings(); // actually some code more than just one function call
        method1(x);
        doOtherThings(); // actually some code more than jus one function call
    }
    void workflow2(int x, int y=1) {
        doThings(); // actually some code; the same as in workflow1()
        method2(x,y);
        doOtherThings(); // actually some code; the same as in workflow1()
    }
private:
    void doThings() {}
    void doOtherThings() {}
    void method1(int x) {}
    void method2(int x, int y) {}
};


int main()
{
    MyClass myClass;
    int x = 0;
    myClass.workflow1(x);
    int y = 2;
    myClass.workflow2(x, y);
}
```

Comment: What version of the standard are you on? C++ 17 has some nice features for this

Comment: I am using C++17. Could you please give more details about "the nice features"? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

Use a lambda approach:

```
#include <functional>

class MyClass
{
public:
    void workflow1(int x) {
        workFlowInternal([x, this] {method1(x); });
    }
    void workflow2(int x, int y = 1) {
        workFlowInternal([x, y, this] {method2(x,y); });
    }
private:

    void workFlowInternal(const std::function<void()> &func) {
        doThings();
        func();
        doOtherThings();
    }


    void doThings() {}
    void doOtherThings() {}
    void method1(int x) {}
    void method2(int x, int y) {}
};
```

Or, use a pointer to member function:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void workflow1(int x) {
        workFlowInternal(&MyClass::method1, x, 0);
    }
    void workflow2(int x, int y = 1) {
        workFlowInternal(&MyClass::method2, x, y);
    }
private:

    void workFlowInternal(void(MyClass::* func)(int, int), int x, int y) {
        doThings();
        (this->*func)(x,y);
        doOtherThings();
    }


    void doThings() {}
    void doOtherThings() {}
    void method1(int x, int ignored=0) {}
    void method2(int x, int y) {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional):

```
#include <optional>

class MyClass
{
 public:
  void workflow(int x, std::optional<int> y = {}) {
    doThings();
    if (!y) method1(x);
    else method2(x, *y);
    doOtherThings();
  }
 private:
  void doThings() { }
  void doOtherThings() { }
  void method1(int x) {  }
  void method2(int x, int y) { }
};

int main() {
  MyClass myClass;
  int x = 0;
  myClass.workflow(x);
  int y = 2;
  myClass.workflow(x, y);
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/zc7nPjfYe)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a templated function like this:

```
template <bool workflow1>
void Workflow(int x, int y=1)
{
    doThings();
    if constexpr (workflow1)
    {
        method1(x);
    }
    else
    {
        method2(x, y);
    }

    doOtherThings();
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    Workflow<true>(x);
    int y = 2;
    Workflow<false>(x, y);
}
```

`if constexpr` statements are decided at compile time, so this will generate two different functions, but you won't have to rewrite the code that is the same. The template argument can be changed from a `bool` to an `enum` or another type if you need to support more than two types.